# Display problem in Notepad++ v5.9.6.2 (Wine 1.3.34)

Tags: wine

I have been encountering a display issue for about 2 months when using Notepad++ with wine on Ubuntu 10.04.

[image]

It happens not only in the display results panel, but also in the editor panel.

Does any of you have this problem? Do you know how to fix it?
Thanks !

Comment: Do you have the NVidia drivers installed?

Comment: Yes I am using NVidia drivers. I think the problem is due to a recent version of either Wine or Notepad++ because I did not have the problem a few months ago.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47875/graphics-problems-with-applications similar?

Comment: Adding the line Option "RenderAccel" "0" in /etc/X11/xorg.conf under  the device section did the trick, as suggested in the bug report of the link you posted. This is weird since I did not have the problem with older versions of Wine/Notepad++. Thank you RobinJ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*as per a comment*

> Adding the line Option "RenderAccel" "0" in /etc/X11/xorg.conf under the device section did the trick, as suggested in the bug report of the link you posted. This is weird since I did not have the problem with older versions of Wine/Notepad++. Thank you RobinJ !